# how to read a json file by hashMap in java

Tags: json

I have a very simple question. I want to read a json file by hashMap in java.

For example I have a json file like this:

```
{
    "list": [
       {
    "ID" : "#12354667",
    "value" : "data1."
}
   {
    "ID" : "#12345789",
    "value" : "data2"
}
```

And whenever I call the id it returns the value. I have written this but I do not know how to read the file. Any help?

Thanks,

```
private JsonReader() throws IOException {

    //readfile?
    this.messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

 public String getValue(final String ID)
    {
        if (this.messages.containsKey(ID))
        {
            return this.messages.get(value);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONParser` and `FileReader` to read your file into your Application. I'm not quite sure if this is what you searched for, but you can try it. You only have to give your `ID` to this method.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\yourFile.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        // loop array
        JSONArray list= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("list");
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           String id= (String) jsonObject.get("ID");
           if(id.equals(hereYourFinalString ID)){
              String value = (String) jsonObject.get("value");
              System.out.println(value);
           }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     }
```